# `undefined` shown in MVC details

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I click on a table row the comments should be displayed on the right. Instead of the comments I see `undefined` though.

[image]

The main goal of the app is to read companies from a database and read and to display comments for each company when I click on the company row in the html table. When I try to read the comment content it says 'undefined' for each comment (Ex: Test Company has 2 comments: "Comment test 1", "Comment test 2"). For this project I used MVC template and EntityCoreFramework.

This is the code that displays the comments :

```
   @section scripts {  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function () {               
                var selectedCompanyId = $("tbody tr:first").data("company-id");
                $("tbody tr:first").addClass("selected");

                $("tbody tr").on("click", function () {                   
                    $("tbody tr").removeClass("selected");
                   
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                   
                    var companyId = $(this).data("company-id");
                    
                    $.get("/Home/GetComments", { companyId: companyId }, function (data) {
                        
                        var commentsHtml = "";
                        data.forEach(function (comment) {
                            commentsHtml += "<div>" + comment.Content + "</div>";
                        });
                       
                        $("#company-comments").html(commentsHtml);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>        
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CompanyDataContext context;

        public HomeController(CompanyDataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var companies = this.context.Companies
                .Select(c => new CompanyViewModel
                {
                    CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Count = c.Comments.Count,
                    Comments = c.Comments.Select(co => new CommentViewModel
                    {
                        CommentCompanyId = co.CompanyId,
                        CommentId = co.CommentId,
                        Content = co.Content
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            return View(companies);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Comment> GetAll()
        {
            return context.Comments.ToList();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetComments(int companyId)
        {
            var company = await this.context.Companies
                .Include(c => c.Comments)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CompanyId == companyId);

            if (company == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var comments = company.Comments.Select(c => new CommentViewModel
            {
                CommentCompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                CommentId = c.CommentId,
                Content = c.Content
            });

            return Ok(comments);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<CompanyApp.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div style="display: flex;" class=" container">
    <div class="box1">
        <table id="my-table" class="my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company ID</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var company in Model)
                {
                    <tr data-company-id="@company.CompanyId">
                        <td>@company.CompanyId</td>
                        <td>@company.Name</td>
                        <td align="center">@company.Count</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="company-comments" class="box2"></div>        
</div>

    @section scripts {  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function () {               
                var selectedCompanyId = $("tbody tr:first").data("company-id");
                $("tbody tr:first").addClass("selected");

                $("tbody tr").on("click", function () {                   
                    $("tbody tr").removeClass("selected");
                   
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                   
                    var companyId = $(this).data("company-id");
                    
                    $.get("/Home/GetComments", { companyId: companyId }, function (data) {
                        
                        var commentsHtml = "";
                        data.forEach(function (comment) {
                            commentsHtml += "<div>" + comment.Content + "</div>";
                        });
                       
                        $("#company-comments").html(commentsHtml);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>        
    }
```

SS with the current result, the comments should be displayed in the fight side(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axh18.png)

Comment: `undefined` is a Javascript concept, it has nothing to do with databases. Check your Javascript code. Remove the unrelated code from the question because it makes it impossible to understand what you're actually asking. Right now, the Javascript snippet is completely hidden. The controller and DTOs have nothing to do with the question, so the only relevant code is completely hidden below the bottom of the question

Comment: What does `comment` contain? JavaScript is case sensitive so `Content` isn't the same as `content`. By convention, JSON attributes are camel-Cased. Try `comment.content`

Comment: try `console.log` on your `comment` variable in the forEach loop - check if it has the `Content` property - sometimes the api will change the case depending on the serialisation setting so it could be `comment.content`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this JS snippet :

```
data.forEach(function (comment) {
    commentsHtml += "<div>" + comment.Content + "</div>";
});
```

change `comment.Content` to `comment.content`.

---

`undefined` is a JavaScript value. It's returned when the code tries to read a non-existent attribute. Since you get two `undefined` values it means there are two `comment` objects but none has a `Content` attribute.

JavaScript is case-sensitive so `Content` and `content` refer to two different attributes. By convention, JSON attribute names are lowercase. ASP.NET MVC follows that convention and serializes `Content` as `content`